# ethics for discriminated

Tags: ethics

If a person belongs to a discriminated and oppressed social and economical group and conducts seemingly unethical behavior in order to ease his condition is that a truly unethical behavior?

For example, if an illegal immigrant steals flowers from industrial flowers fields to sell them in order for him to have at least some money to survive, is that unethical?

Or if an under-fed slave steals food from his master in order to obtain enough nutrition?

Or if a person coming from an authoritarian oppressive and discriminating state (like Russia) is forging some documents for him to easily pass through a senseless, artificial and over-complicated bureaucratic procedure?

Or if a person in poverty takes a bus without having a ticket, since he does not have money?

To be honest, I am, as a person coming from the former Soviet Union, is the most concerned with people's from the EU reactions to some of the shady habits Eastern European people have. Being used to the fact that social institutions are not just and legal system is firstly idiotic and secondly basically not functioning, we find our more efficient workarounds, without considering them like something bad at all. However, in most of the cases this shocks in a negative way my EU friends and that makes me angry.

Comment: Isn't this dependant on the specific term of oppression that is used? Would you mind clarifing?

Comment: If you accept Rousseau's "social contract", we obey laws to protect others because those laws also protect us. When those laws fail to protect us, we are relieved of our contractual obligation to follow those laws. Having said that, I'd have different answers for your various scenarios.